# Connect Outlook to our Exchange Server 2003 over the Internet

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, exchange-2003, outlook-2003

We have a one mail server here on site running Exchange 2003, however we are part of a large exchange group - there are some 10 outlook mail servers around the world and we are just one of the administratove groups. We can access email via OWA and I have checked our server and is a RPC-HTTP Back end server and RPC is installed.
We can connect via VPN, on lan, and OWA but I cannot get it to work via the internet. Any suggestions

Tests with using autodiscover as per request

```
ExRCA is attempting to test Autodiscover for xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx
Testing Autodiscover failed.

Test Steps

Attempting each method of contacting the Autodiscover service.
The Autodiscover service couldn't be contacted successfully by any method.

Test Steps

Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml
Testing of this potential Autodiscover URL failed.

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.

Additional Details
IP addresses returned: 67.107.26.30
Testing TCP port 443 on host xxxxxxxxx.com to ensure it's listening and open.
The port was opened successfully.
Testing the SSL certificate to make sure it's valid.
The SSL certificate failed one or more certificate validation checks.

Test Steps

ExRCA is attempting to obtain the SSL certificate from remote server xxxxxxxxx.com on port 443.
ExRCA successfully obtained the remote SSL certificate.

Additional Details
Remote Certificate Subject: CN=www.xxxxxxxxx.com, OU=Domain Control Validated, O=www.xxxxxxxxx.com, Issuer: SERIALNUMBER=xxxxxxxxx, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority, OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, S=Arizona, C=US.
Validating the certificate name.
The certificate name was validated successfully.

Additional Details
Host name xxxxxxxxx.com was found in the Certificate Subject Alternative Name entry.
Testing the certificate date to confirm the certificate is valid.
Date validation failed.

Additional Details
The certificate has expired. NotAfter = 7/16/2010 11:51:38 PM (UTC)
Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://autodiscover.xxxxxxxxx.com/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml
Testing of this potential Autodiscover URL failed.

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name autodiscover.xxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.
The host name couldn't be resolved.
 Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it

Additional Details
Host autodiscover.xxxxxxxxx.com couldn't be resolved in DNS InfoDomainNonexistent.
Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the HTTP redirect method.
The attempt to contact Autodiscover using the HTTP Redirect method failed.

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name autodiscover.xxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.
The host name couldn't be resolved.
 Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it

Additional Details
Host autodiscover.xxxxxxxxx.com couldn't be resolved in DNS InfoDomainNonexistent.
Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the DNS SRV redirect method.
ExRCA failed to contact the Autodiscover service using the DNS SRV redirect method.

Test Steps

Attempting to locate SRV record _autodiscover._tcp.xxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.
The Autodiscover SRV record wasn't found in DNS.
 Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it
```

Comment: Maybe you could give us more information on what happens (or doesn't happen) when you try to connect via the internet? Also, what OS and Outlook version are the clients running? In addition, test connectivy from the following and post the results: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com

Comment: OS - Server 2003 / Exchange 2003 - OS of laptop Windows 7 - Client Outlook2003, When I try to send and recieve when its on wireless and all the set up has been put on, the logon box appears, all are entered correctly its starts to send and receieve and then hangs

Comment: If it's the first time you've set it up on a computer, it'll hang for a while to update the mailbox, especially if the mailbox in question is large.

Answer (score 0):

Go to testexchangeconnectivity.com to get to the root of the problem. All you should need is port 80/443 open, and then configure the Outlook clients correctly (you might need to set it to basic authentication, but make sure you're using SSL along with it). Also, make sure the ValidPorts registry key is configured correctly (it should include the public `domain.com` that your company uses, not just the internal `domain.local` name).

Comment: I am not familiar with the ValidPorts registry key - where should I look for this.

Comment: Testing RPC/HTTP connectivity.
  The RPC/HTTP test failed.

Attempting to resolve the host name xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.
  The host name resolved successfully.
  
 Additional Details
  IP addresses returned: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 Testing TCP port 443 on host xxxxxxxxx.com to ensure it's listening and open.
  The port was opened successfully.

Testing the SSL certificate to make sure it's valid.
  The SSL certificate failed one or more certificate validation checks.
  
 Test Steps
  
 ExRCA is attempting to obtain the SSL certificate from remote server xxxxxxxxxxx.com on port 443.

Comment: ExRCA successfully obtained the remote SSL certificate.
  
 Additional Details
  Remote Certificate Subject: CN=www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com, OU=Domain Control Validated, O=www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com, Issuer: SERIALNUMBER=xxxxxxxx, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority, OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, S=Arizona, C=US.
 Validating the certificate name.
  The certificate name was validated successfully.

Additional Details
  Host name xxxxxxxxxxx.com was found in the Certificate

Comment: Subject Alternative Name entry.
 Certificate trust is being validated.
  Certificate trust validation failed.Test Steps
  
 ExRCA is attempting to build certificate chains for certificate CN=www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com, OU=Domain Control Validated, O=www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com.
  A certificate chain couldn't be constructed for the certificate.

The certificate chain has errors. Chain status = NotTimeValid.
 Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://autodiscover.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml
  Testing of this potential Autodiscover URL failed.

Comment: Attempting to resolve the host name autodiscover.xxxxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.
  The host name couldn't be resolved.
   Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it
  
 Additional Details
  Host autodiscover.xxxxxxxxxxx.com couldn't be resolved in DNS InfoDomainNonexistent.
 Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the HTTP redirect method.
  The attempt to contact Autodiscover using the HTTP Redirect method failed.
  
 Test Steps
Attempting to resolve the host name autodiscover.xxxxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.

Comment: The host name couldn't be resolved.
   Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it
  
 Additional Details
  Host autodiscover.xxxxxxxxxxx.com couldn't be resolved in DNS InfoDomainNonexistent.
 Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the DNS SRV redirect method.
  ExRCA failed to contact the Autodiscover service using the DNS SRV redirect method.

Test Steps
  
 Attempting to locate SRV record _autodiscover._tcp.xxxxxxxxxxx.com in DNS.
  The Autodiscover SRV record wasn't found in DNS.

Comment: It looks like you selected the Outlook Autodiscover option for your test. Exchange 2003 doesn't use Autodiscover. You want to select the "Microsoft Office Outlook Connectivity Tests" with the "Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTP)" option.

Comment: Also, please post all of those status messages in the original question. It's very messy and hard to read down here.

Comment: I have updated with the test as per joequerty